# Does string(const char* myString, int myStringSize) copy all the myString bytes?

Tags: c++, string, char

Lets suppose I have this:

```
const char * myString = {100, 102, 0, 104};
std::string resultString(myString);
```

Will resultString contain the 4 bytes I had in myString, or will it have only the first 2 since it encounters a \0 in the third place?

Testing with online compilers it copies the whole myString, but I need to be sure that this is intended, since the documentation does not clarify this.

Thanks!

Comment: The initialization of `myString` doesn't do what you expect. You can't initialize a pointer with multiple values, and your compiler should tell you that (if not then enable more warnings). Use an *array* instead. With your current code you have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean specific characters then use the actual characters instead.

Comment: Testing with online compiler shows that your code doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/M4s4vEdWM. And yes, this overload of [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) requires a null-terminated string, which means it will stop at `0`. Use `std::string(myString, 4)` to get all characters.

Comment: `resultString` will contain nothing because your code won't even compile.. Did you mean `const char myString []= {100, 102, 0, 104};`? What do you `resultString` expect to contain?

Comment: `char const* s = "hello\0world"; string hello(s), hzw(s, 11), hzwz(s, 12), alt_hzw(s, s+12), alt_hzwz(s, s+13);`